# Changing DataGridView Column Width automatically

Tags: c#, datagridview, column-width

I have a DataGridView with 3 columns, and I want to set their widths to adjust automatically according to the text inside the cells, while filling the whole DataGridView space. If I use the following code:

```
dgvAcionamentosCadastrados.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

The columns adjust to the size of the text inside, but no longer fill the whole DataGridView space. If I use this other piece of code instead:

```
dgvAcionamentosCadastrados.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

The opposite happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying you want the columns to size *proportionally* to their content? Are you saying you want to fill the whole space, but you don't want any of the content to be truncated? It's not even clear exactly what you want to do here.

Comment: Yes, I want them to size proportionally to their content. However, if I do this by adding the first method I mentioned, the total width of the columns inside the DataGrid is smaller than the DataGrid's width itself (aka blank space inside the DataGrid)

Answer (score 0):

After the data has been inserted into the grid, try setting the width of each column of the grid to autosize:

```
for (int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[i].Width = -2;
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.columnheader.width.aspx